# this.props.children not re-rendered on parent state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a piece of code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Child/>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

class Container extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Container render');
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.setState({})}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Child render');
    return <h1>Hi</h1>
  }
}

export default App;
```

When clicking on 'Hi' msg, only `Container` component keeps re-rendering but `Child` component is not re-rendered.

**Why is `Child` component not re-rendered on `Container` state change?**

I would reason, that it doesn't happen due to it being a property of `Container` component, but still `this.props.child` is evaluated to a `Child` component in JSX, so not sure.

```
<div onClick={() => this.setState({})}>
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```

Full example https://codesandbox.io/s/529lq0rv2n (check console log)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The question is quite old, but since you didn't seem to get a satisfying answer I'll give it a shot too.

As you have observed by yourself, changing

```
// Scenario A

<div onClick={() => this.setState({})}>
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```

to

```
// Scenario B

<div onClick={() => this.setState({})}>
  <Child />
</div>
```

will in fact, end up with

> Container render
>   Child render

in the console, every time you click.

Now, to quote you

> As fas as I understand, if setState() is triggered, render function of
>   Container component is called and all child elements should be
>   re-rendered.

You seemed to be very close to understanding what is happening here.

So far, you are correct, since the `Container`'s `render` is executed, so must the components returned from it call their own `render` methods.

Now, as you also said, correctly,

```
<Child />

// is equal to

React.createElement(Child, {/*props*/}, /*children*/)
```

In essence, what you get from the above is just an `object` describing what to show on the screen, *a React Element*.

The key here is to understand *when* the `React.createElement(Child, {/*props*/}, /*children*/)` execution happened, in each of the scenarios above.

So let's see what is happening:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Child/>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

class Container extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Container render');
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.setState({})}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Child render');
    return <h1>Hi</h1>
  }
}
```

You can rewrite the return value of `App` like this:

```
<Container>
  <Child/>
</Container>

// is equal to

React.createElement(
  Container, 
  {}, 
  React.createElement(
    Child, 
    {}, 
    {}
  )
)

// which is equal to a React Element object, something like

{
  type: Container,
  props: {
    children: {
      type: Child,    // |
      props: {},      // +---> Take note of this object here
      children: {}    // |
    }
  }
}
```

And you can also rewrite the return value of `Container` like this:

```
<div onClick={() => this.setState({})}>
  {this.props.children}
</div>

// is equal to

React.createElement(
  'div', 
  {onClick: () => this.setState({})}, 
  this.props.children
)

// which is equal to React Element

{
  type: 'div',
  props: {
    children: this.props.children
  }
}
```

Now, `this.props.children` is the same thing as the one included in the `App`'s returned React Element:

```
{
  type: Child,
  props: {},
  children: {}
}
```

And to be exact, these two things are *referentially* the same, meaning it's the exact same thing in memory, in both cases.

Now, no matter how many times `Container` get's re-rendered, since its `children` are always referentially the same thing between renders (because that React Element was created in the `App` level and it has no reason to change), they don't get re-rendered.

In short, **React doesn't bother to render a React Element again if it is referentially (`===`) equal to what it was in the previous render.**

Now, if you were to change the `Container` you would have:

```
<div onClick={() => this.setState({})}>
  <Child />
</div>

// is equal to

React.createElement(
  'div', 
  {onClick: () => this.setState({})}, 
  React.createElement(
    Child, 
    {}, 
    {}
  ) 
)

// which is equal to

{
  type: 'div',
  props: {
    children: {
      type: Child,
      props: {},
      children: {}
    }
  }
}
```

**However** in this case, if you were to re-render `Container`, it will have to re-execute

```
React.createElement(
  Child, 
  {}, 
  {}
)
```

**for every render**. This will result in React Elements that are referentially different between renders, so React will actually re-render the `Child` component as well, even though the end result will be the same.

[Reference](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3226)

Comment: Great explanation! Replacing "return this.props.children" with "return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child=>React.isValidElement(child) ? React.cloneElement(child) : child)" forced my children to render on parent state update.

Comment: just curious, if we use this component composition, and assume we will have not only one child component, what will happen? I experimented here[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-robinson-0ki81?file=/src/index.js). this was as expected. But [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-robinson-0ki81?file=/src/index.js:590-664). we have a child component bubbling up event, and we update state in the input field parent compoennt, and the child component button is always rendered. shouldn't that be the same reference every time and react jsut skip?

Comment: I think you have accidentally posted the same link twice, it's the one you say it always renders the children. That's because, you have lifted the state up, to the level of the App component. If its state changes it has to re execute the function (render) of everything that it returns. So, every time you type something, its state gets updated so the Inputfield and the Button get rerendered every time. Try moving the state in the Inputfield component and see what happens :) (https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-hooks-m65l7?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

The `<Child />` component is not re-rendered because the props have not changed. React uses the concept of Virtual DOM which is a representation of your components and their data.

If the props of a component do not change the component is not re-rendered. This is what keeps React fast.

In you example there are no props sent down to `Child`, so it will never be re-rendered. If you want it to re-render each time (why would you ?), you can for example use a pure function

```
const Child = () => <h1>Hi</h1>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As fas as I understand, if setState() is triggered, render function of Container component is called and all child elements should be re-rendered. I could use <Child/> instead of {this.props.children} and re-render will be done each time, even there are no props to update. Check [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6l9vmx5nnw)

Comment: `<Child />` is rendered by `App`, That's why it won't be re-rendered when `Container ` is rendered. All your `Container ` does - it just returns the passed value. You can trigger the re-rendering by doing `React.cloneElement(this.props.children)`

Comment: I thought so at the beginning, but how would you explain initial rendering then? When app is initially mounted Child is rendered after Container is rendered (see console log). If Child was rendered in an App, "Child rendered" should appear before "Container rendered" during initial mount, should't it?

Answer (score 1):

Change `{this.props.children}` to `<Child />` in Container component, (now you can remove `<Child />` from App component).

If you are clicking the div you will get both the 'Child render' and 'Container render' in console.

(In this example your child is static component. Then there is no point for the re-rendering.)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of case when <Child /> is used instead of {this.props.children}. Still don't see the difference in JSX as this.props.children will return the same <Child/> element. Could you please elaborate more what you mean by saying _your child is static component_ ?

Comment: The Child component content is static (The content is not going to change any time). In this case no need of re-rendering the component. But your Child needs to be re-rendered if you are using some values which you will get from Container component, passed through props, and that is going to change by the time.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. Yes we can call it a static one. It still doesn't explain why when used as a <Child/> instead of {this.props.children} it will be re-rendered each time. Check the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6l9vmx5nnw)