# Incorrect understanding of React rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two blocks of React code and I am trying to understand how the rendering works.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function A({ children }) {
  console.log("A");
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setState((state) => state + 1);
  }, []);
  return children;
}

function B() {
  console.log("B");
  return <C />;
}

function C() {
  console.log("C");
  return null;
}

function D() {
  console.log("D");
  return null;
}

function App() {
  console.log("App");
  return (
    <div>
      <A>
        <B />
      </A>
      <D />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Output of above code is:

```
App 
A 
B 
C 
D 
A
```

I was expecting the output would be: **App A B C D A B C** suggesting that B and C components would be re-rendered as their parent(A)'s state had changed. Why is the output just **App A B C D A**?

I have another code as follows:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function A({ children }) {
  console.log("A");
  return children;
}

function B() {
  console.log("B");
  return <C />;
}

function C() {
  console.log("C");
  return null;
}

function D() {
  console.log("D");
  return null;
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setState((state) => state + 1);
  }, []);
  console.log("App");
  return (
    <div>
      <A>
        <B />
      </A>
      <D />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Output in the above code is as per my expectation:

```
App 
A 
B 
C 
D 
App 
A 
B 
C 
D
```

What is the problem in my understanding?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567429/this-props-children-not-re-rendered-on-parent-state-change which is similar to your question

Comment: **Great** find @sodhankit!

Comment: Re the error from React on the Stack Snippets I added: [It's a bug in the UMD build of React](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24221), they have a fix, they just haven't quite released it yet.